# Bluehost MySQL Country Specific Characters Encoding

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, utf-8

I have just moved my site from godaddy to bluehost. Everything works just great  with my new host provider, except come encoding issues.

My site is build on Wordpress. However, I have set 2 MySQL databses. The first one is for WP only, while I use the second one for my custom application, which is integrated in WP.

Like said, I had the same structure and setup on Godaddy, where this was working.

I exported both db's on GoDaddy via phpMyAdmin and then imported them on Bluehost. All the site files were moved with FileZilla.

If I look at the new databases on Bluehost, they are utf8_general_ci encoded, which is ok. Also the website has utf8 in header, etc.

I have an interesting situation. Since I am from Slovenia, we have some special characters, like Č, Š, Ž, and small ones č, š, ž. The Wordpress content prints all these characters just fine, while I have problems printing these characters correctly from my second (application) database, You can see my problem on this link: http://www.slotenis.si/baza-igralcev/

Any ideas what could be wrong?

I tried the online chat support with Bluehost, but we couldn't solve it. Must say, they are very helpful, but were left out of ideas on this one.

Thanks,
Goran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of Googling, I found the solution. I only need to add the following line after my connection string. I use mysqli...

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
**$con->set_charset("utf8");**
```

Now up and running. The credit for solution goes to:
http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/how-to-avoid-character-encoding-problems-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

Make your application set the character encoding of the DB connection to UTF-8 when it connects. How to do that depends on the API you use to access the database. In PDO for example you would add `charset=utf8` to the connection string.